# Deploying React app to Github Pages issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I've deployed my react app to github pages, now I want to deploy an updated version, but when I run `npm run deploy` it returns me:

```
EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/Users/progbash/Desktop/milijonasroziu/build/static/css'


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! milijonasroziu@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the milijonasroziu@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/progbash/.npm/_logs/2020-02-19T22_35_43_611Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! milijonasroziu@0.1.0 predeploy: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the milijonasroziu@0.1.0 predeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: tried `sudo npm run deploy` ?

Comment: Could you please attach a log from /Users/progbash/.npm/_logs/2020-02-19T22_35_43_611Z-debug.log